# Laravel Accessing Array Data In View

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I know I am very close, I'm just stuck and can't figure out this last step.

I'm trying to echo out some information in my blade template, but I'm getting the following error: **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$Moniker**

Here is my controller, which returns the `$data` variable to the view:

```
$user = User::where('id', $request)->get();
$data = array(
    'images'  => $images,
    'user'   => $user
);
return view('a_profile')->with('data', $data);
```

Here is my view:

```
<title>{{$data['user']->Moniker}} | My Company | Baltimore, MD</title>
```

How do I get the `Moniker` which is a column in my `users` table to echo out, in this case? Thank you! :)

Comment: Are user and moniker have relationships?

Comment: @aldrin27 Sorry, come again?

Comment: Can you `print_r($user)` ?

Comment: @aldrin27 It is kind of a mess and it has sensitive data in it, but there is a relationship, as `Moniker` is a column in my `users` table.

Comment: Okay I understand. If you want to get the columns in that use foreach. For example: `@foreach($data['user'] as $key => $val) {{$val->Moniker}} @endforeach` in your blade.

Comment: @aldrin27 Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `get()` method will return you records in `array into array` format like this,

your query,

```
$user = User::where('id', $request)->get();
```

result would be this

```
array(
   array(
     'id'  =>1,
     'name'=>'xyz' 
   )
)
```

So, in your view, instead of looping, you can access the column doing this,

```
<title>{{$data['user'][0]->Moniker}} | My Company | Baltimore, MD</title>
```

So convert your query into this `first()`, because you want to return single record,

```
$user = User::where('id', $request)->first();
```

this will return the result into single array format

```
array(
  'id'  =>1,
  'name'=>'xyz' 
)
```

and you can access into your view, simple doing this

```
<title>{{$data['user']->Moniker}} | My Company | Baltimore, MD</title>
```